# Drupal Views - how to show a sporting club's "longest run"?

Tags: views

I have a database of football games like this:

date, opponent, venue, our score, their score etc

Im trying to find a way to search the database and find the "longest run";  eg the longest winning run or maybe the longest losing run

a season might look like ( there are decades of "seasons")

win, win, loss, loss, loss, win, win, win, win, win, loss.

any suggestions?  ( have to maintain this myself so can't do php)

thanks

Comment: Are the individual games proper Drupal Entities (nodes) or is it a custom database table? In both cases you will probably need to write a custom module (only the approach is different) since you need to get several games (nodes) in a specific order (by date) and then calculate the streaks. An alternative without a custom module (only works if games are nodes) would be to add a new computed field that is actually a simple counter (+1) which resets to 1 if the outcome changes (win > loss or loss > win). Still hard to achieve since you would need a reference to the last game.